# ssh+sudo+dump on server cannot be restored locally

Tags: ssh, software-recommendation, backup, ext4, restore

I have inherited an Ubuntu 14.04 server that I need to create a sandboxed copy of locally in VirtualBox to experiment with as part of preparing to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, as we strongly suspect it is not a straight-forward update.

In order to do so, I would like a complete backup of the server file systems to restore in a blank virtual machine,  which I traditionally would do for ext4 using `dump` as root on the server to a file, copy that file locally and `restore` it.   Unfortunately there is not room on the server to hold the resulting file for the root file system.

I therefore have experimented with dumping to standard out in an ssh connection and capturing the output locally, similar to:

```
ssh -t me@there "echo MYPASSWORD | sudo -S dump -y -f - /boot 2>/dev/null " > boot.dump
```

(The standard error redirect is to avoid having the dump messages mixed into the dump file)

Unfortunately `restore` (also under 14.04) dislikes this dump file as it fails the checksums.  If I create the dump file on the server and copy it, it is fine.

Most resources on the net runs the ssh command on the same machine as the dump command, so the file descriptors are not mixed together.

Any suggestions?

---

EDIT:  Some experimentation with the `/boot` file system, show that the file created by dump directly is 125932218 bytes, and the file created from the ssh command is 125465751 bytes, with a difference of about 466000 which - using the technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417454/53897  - appears to be `\r` characters (0d hex) inserted ahead of a `\n` character (0a hex).  So this is not about extra messages being merged silently into the datastream but about not being binary clean.  Interesting.

Comment: You could tray to use `sshfs` in order to mount your local file system on the remote server, then create the dump file inside the mountpoint... I'm doing some backups in this way.

Comment: Try creating a `NOPASSWD` rule for sudo so that it doesn't ask for a password for this command, and then running without `-t`, `echo ... |`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked about the "why are \r's inserted" bit at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/633543/4869 where it was quickly pointed out that this is a feature of the pseudo-tty allocated with `-t` which then needs to be turned off again.  See that question for details.